# GhostScript fonts folder removed from later versions?

Tags: fonts, ghostscript

I have some C# code that uses GhostScript (calls it as a process) to convert postscript to PDF.  Currently I am using GS v9.06.  I noticed earlier versions of GS (i.e. v8.60) installed a fonts (and resource) folder as part of the installation process. Are the fonts in the fonts folder no longer necessary for later versions of GS like v9.06 since the installer for that version does not include them?  -AND-  Really the same question for the files in the resource folder.
The code I've written against v9.06 seems to be working so far without the fonts folder being present.  NOTE: I'm running GS under Windows 7.

Here is a typical call:

```
gswin64c -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -q -dNOCCFONTS 
  -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook 
  -dAutoRotatePages=/PageByPage -sOutputFile=ex.pdf -c .setpdfwrite -f ex.ps
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ghostscript binary releases on Windows have all the resources built into a ROM file system (ie they are part of the executable). Other operating systems differ, particularly on Linux where packagers may or may not follow our lead.

You have to go back a long way to reach a time when this wasn't the case, the earliest version I currently have installed (8.71) uses the ROM file systems and that is more than 6 years old.

The fonts and other resources are still present, but not on disk.

As regards your command line, I personally would not use PDFSETTINGS, as it affects a myriad of controls probably not setting them all the way you want. I would select the controls I wanted individually.

-dNOCCFONTS does nothing any more and was only ever a debugging control, you should not use it.

You don't need "-c .setpdfwrite -f" any more. Haven't done for many versions.

Comment: I feel comfortable removing the -dNOCCFONTS but not sure about .setpdfwrite.  That argument seems to be doing some performance stuff.  The info about the ROM is interesting and helpful.  The fact that GS is working fine without these folders/data is more proof, but your comments put my mind at ease a bit.  thanks

Comment: All .setpdfwrite does is set a large threshold before the garbage collector runs. This does have some performance implications, but realistically not for any normal job. Really, its not required. If it makes you feel more comfortable about it, I am the maintainer for the pdfwrite device, and I can assure you that it is not really required. The only reason the routine still exists is because many people are using it (without understanding why), and if I removed it they would get errors and open bug reports.....